# how do i find html of struts?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1, struts-config

I am really new and not familiar with this...I am trying to edit this folder with a ton of files in it including .xml....I need to find the html part but it is using "struts" and I don't know much about it other than it being a Java MVC framework...

How can I find the html part? the URL is http://localhost:8080/ContractView.do

I searched inside 1 of the xml file and found this which might be of use:

```
<action name="DashBoardForm" path="/DashBoard" type="com.manageengine.servicedesk.dashboard.action.DashBoardAction">
    <forward name="viewDashBoard" path="/dashboard/Dashboard.jsp"/>
</action>
```

Any Ideas on how I can get the html?

I want to basically add an extra option to the menu.

I am really new to this and just trying to add an extra menu to the navigation bar so that I can embed php files in it that it will link to..

it is a software, can be downloaded at 
http://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk/download.html

Comment: We can't view the URL because it's referencing something on your machine. If you can upload it somewhere else, people can take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dashboard/Dashboard.jsp` should be a view page containing html. In Struts the `struts-config.xml` file dictates which request gets served by which servlet. In your case, `ContactView.do` should have a mapping to an action class. Look for the xml config line in that file that contains `path="/ViewContact"`.

In the actual jsp page you may see a mix of struts constructs - (ie. `s:<some_tag>`), JSTL (ie. `c:<some_tag>`, and pure html). However, they all obviously get translated to HTML when you are viewing it in a client (ie. browsers).

Another thing you may want to check out is whether it is using [tiles](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-tiles/index.html). A lot of times the view page may be defined in the `tiles-defition.xml` file. So that may be another place for you to look where `ContactView` jsp may be defined at. If it is using tiles then you will find the name of tile definition in the struts-config.xml and then find the actual JSP path in the tiles-definition.xml.

**UPDATE**

After you added the link to struts-config.xml, I can tell you exactly which JSP your request goes to which is originally what you asked in your post.

Take a look at the following snippet:-

```
    <action name="ContractViewForm" path="/ContractView" scope="request" type="com.adventnet.servicedesk.contract.action.ContractViewAction" input="ContractListView.jsp">
                <forward name="contractListView" path="/contract/ContractListView.jsp?task=ContractListView"/>
                <forward name="newContract" path="/contract/ContractDef.jsp?task=ContractDef"/>
            </action>

<form-bean name="ContractViewForm" type="com.adventnet.servicedesk.contract.form.ContractViewForm"/>
```

From this snippet as you can see depending on how the page was forwarded from the previous action (ie. form submit) it will either go to `/contract/ContractListView.jsp` or `/contract/ContractDef.jsp` . The backing action class is `com.adventnet.servicedesk.contract.action.ContractViewAction` which is the class where all the business logic processing starts. The form is `com.adventnet.servicedesk.contract.form.ContractViewForm`  where all the form fields are stored and it is at `requqest` scope.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Jeff Hodge - Did you find the line in your struts config XML that goes to ContactView? Perhaps paste your struts-config.xml in your post.

Comment: I am nto really sure how I can find the html and modify it to add an additional option to the menu..

Comment: @Jeff Hodge - you add the option/drop down menu in the JSP page. Are you new to Java/JEE? Then I recommend you google JSP tutorials to see how it is done.